# Return an equivalent array without the zeroes in R?

Tags: arrays, r

I have a one-dimensional and two dimensional array. For the one-dimensional array, I'd like a count of non-zero elements, the indices of the non-zero elements, and a good way to return the same array without the zeroes:

i.e.:

```
c(0, 0.09017892, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01685147, -0.06063455, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

to:

```
 c(0.09017892,  0.01685147,  -0.06063455)
```

Similarly, with the two-dimensional array with zeroes, I'd like to return a two-dimensional array without the zeroes:

i.e.

```
      [,1]        [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]        [,7]      [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
 [2,]    0  1.00000000    0    0    0    0 -0.09929266 0.1169883    0     0     0     0
 [3,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
 [4,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
 [5,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
 [6,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
 [7,]    0 -0.09929266    0    0    0    0  1.00000000 0.5697163    0     0     0     0
 [8,]    0  0.11698827    0    0    0    0  0.56971626 1.0000000    0     0     0     0
 [9,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
[10,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
[11,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
[12,]    0  0.00000000    0    0    0    0  0.00000000 0.0000000    0     0     0     0
```

to:

```
            [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  1.00000000 -0.09929266 0.1169883
[2,] -0.09929266  1.00000000 0.5697163
[3,]  0.11698827  0.56971626 1.0000000
```

Comment: Try `x[x!=0]`, `which(x!=0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the non-zero elements:

```
x[x!=0]
```

To get the indices:

```
which(x!=0)
```

To get the number of nonzero elements:

```
sum(x!=0)
```

The two-dimensional `array` case is unclear. What happens if some elements of rows and columns have both zeroes and nonzero elements? However, in your example:

```
x[rowSums(x!=0)>0,colSums(x!=0)>0]
#            [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
#[1,]  1.00000000 -0.09929266 0.1169883
#[2,] -0.09929266  1.00000000 0.5697163
#[3,]  0.11698827  0.56971626 1.0000000
```